# How to make float : left work same as table-cell?

Tags: html, css

I have made two CSS layouts, one by using `display:table` and the other by using `float:left`. When using float, the `black` `div` seems to overlap behind the colored `div`'s above it. How to make [this](https://jsfiddle.net/qgjkhy9h/) look similar to [this](https://jsfiddle.net/un5kpoqp/)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add clear both

```
.image-block
{
  height:300px;
  background-color:black;
    clear:both;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By looking at the examples you gave, the black box div is outside the div of the colored boxes div, ex:

```
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="colors">
    <div class="col1 float-left"></div>
    <div class="col2 float-left"></div>
    <div class="col3 float left"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="black-box"></div>
</div>

<style>
  .float-left { float: left; }
  .col1 { background-color: red; }
  .col2 { background-color: blue; }
  .col3 { background-color: green; }
  .black-box { background-color: black; }
</style>
```

...and don't forget to add the CSS for the sizes, etc. I just gave you the skeleton...